# WCF client wrapper thread safety

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, thread-safety

I have WCF service

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class ClientAPI : IClientAPI { ... }
```

and .NET wrapper generated for this service when I add `Service Reference`.

Is that wrapper object thread safe? I mean can I call methods for this client object from different threads without synchronizing access to the object itself?

Comment: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/12/18/concurrent-channel-performance.aspx

Comment: Thanks. So it is thread safe. Why don't you post it as answer, so I can rate it and close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with such model your service instance will be created once, and each query will be handled consequentially. But you have to check your service state, because if it fails, you have to create new instance. It would work like this, in a single thread
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain in more details why should I check for state and why should it fail?

Comment: @axe If your service get the exception, which is not handled properly, your service falls into state Faulted, and all your clients will get CommunicationObjectFaultedException. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041.aspx about service states. And according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789039.aspx you have to recover it - "Create a new object."